# C++ My String class: Pointer doesn't work

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm building my own string class in c++ 11 and I have a memory problem.

in main:

```
MyString str1;     //Works ok, constructor creates empty char array.
const char* pointer1 = str1.c_str(); //Return the pointer to the array.
str1.Reserve(5); 

// Now, when I use the Reverse method in string1, Pointer1 is 
// pointing to the old memory address.
```

How to I change the array data in str1, but to the memory address?

With aother words, How do I fix this so that:

```
pointer1 == str1.c_str();
```

Reserve method:

```
void reserve(int res)
{
    capacity = NewSize(size + res,0 , capacity); //Method to find the best cap.

    char* oldData = data;

    data = new char[capacity];
    memcpy(data, oldData, capacity);
    oldData = data;
    //delete[] data;

    data[(size)] = '\0';
}
```

This returns all the right data, but when I do "oldData = data", the memory address is lost.

I appreciate all help, thanks!

Comment: Since `oldData` is supposed to point to the previous location, why are you reassigning it to the value of `data` instead of doing `delete[] oldData`?

Comment: Why are you doing this: `const char* pointer1 = str1.c_str();str1.Reserve(5);`? This can't work unless you intend to make the promise that str1.c_str() never changes. Your users have to be mindful that changes to the string can result in a change to pointer and only use the return value from c_str() in a scope where the string object is guaranteed not to change.

Comment: [c_str() documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) clearly show that this is undefined behavior.

Comment: in the Reserve method, **data** is the char*. What I'm trying to do is:
1. Save the old data in OldData
2. use **new** on Data to create a new array. (This is where the adress is lost)
3. Copy the old data into the new data.

Comment: Egads, in a word, you can't.

Comment: You don't need to copy the old data into the new data, reserve did that for you. that's what the memcpy does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is if there is a way to get a return value from your string class which will always point to the current string array. There are a number of ways to do this but generally this indicates bad design/implementation.

The more normal way to do this would be to advise API users that the result of c_str() is invalidated by any subsequent modifications to the object: don't keep the pointer, just call c_str() again.

Two obvious options are: a) a pointer to the pointer, very dangerous because now someone outside your class can tweak it, b) provide a wrapper class which encapsulates a pointer-to-pointer without allowing modifications.

```
template<typename T>
struct ReadOnlyPointer {
    T* m_ptr;
    ... operator * ...
    ... operator -> ...
    ... operator T ...
};

ReadOnlyPointer<const char*> pointer = str1.pointer();
```

There also appear to be at least a couple of issues with your "reserve" function.

1. You push a '\0' at data[0] even though size might be zero.

   MyString a;
   a.reserve(0); // crash? you wrote to the first byte of a zero length array.
2. After copying the data from oldData to data, for some reason you assign the value of 'data' to 'oldData' and then never use 'oldData' again - this is a memory leak.
3. Your memcpy uses 'capacity' instead of 'size' so it may be over-copying.

Consider instead:

```
// ensure we have an additional 'res' bytes.
// caution: unlike stl and boost reserve, these are
// additional bytes, not total bytes.
void reserve(int res)
{
    int newCapacity = NewSize(m_size + res, 0, m_capacity); //Method to find the best cap.
    if(newCapacity <= m_capacity)
        return;

    char* newData = new char[newCapacity];
    memcpy(newData, m_data, m_size);
    delete[] m_data;        // release the old allocation
    m_data = newData;
    m_capacity = newCapacity;
}
```

The extra `data[(size)] = '\0';` could be the cause of your string becoming truncated if you are not changing the value of size elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time explaning this. I found out that I've misunderstood the meaning of c_str(), and learned a bit more about pointers. Thank you once again!